# FME Data Tranform and Concatenate Tables in DB without Key from Access to SQL

Tags: sql-server, fme-form, ms-access

I have been able to do a conversion (in FME2013) from an Access DB to a SQL Express DB(in Desktop Workbench), adding some transformers to grab data from three of the tables, two of which have primary keys, and running a SQL query executer I can populate a new table;  querying out needed information from all three, (or inner join on the two with the key) this is all done one DBs at a time because the primary keys repeat.

I would now like to grab multiple Access DB’s all at once and do the same thing  only grouping them together based on the DBs they originate from adding a new primary key field containing the file name of the Access DB in that field.

When I use the Full Filename Attribute from the FilemnamePartExtractor it combines all of the selected filenames adding special characters (“,**) I have removed them using the StringReplacer.
I am at a point where I cannot seem to move forward successfully, due to my limited experience working with FME.

I am also wondering if this is the correct approach or is there a more straightforward method?

[image]

In the first and third writer I am using the FilemnamePartExtractor, StringReplacer, StringConcatenator and the BulkAttributeRenamer and dropping the values into a new SourceData… field.

Comment: use the option 'SQL Statement to Before after Transaction' on your DB sources then store the primary keys (pk) to a attribute pk_1, pk_2, pk_3 etc.

Comment: you need to post your edit as answer.

Answer (score 1):

After some back and forth with FME and becoming more familiar with it’s Workbench I have come up with the following solution.

[image]
[image]
 [image]

I solved this problem by using only the inline query and the Batch Deploy… located under the File menu; running the Batch Deploy initializes a wizard where it runs the query(s) and writers to completion on each input DB one at a time.

[image]
Producing the following desired output.
 [image]
The result:
Where the SEGMENTID field is now assigned and used as the identifier for each DISPLAY_NAME field classification.